# solr/browse gives page not found error.

Tags: solr

How to make browse page load ?   I have added handler as given in the page
https://wiki.apache.org/solr/VelocityResponseWriter

Still not working. Can any one brief me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to check:

1. Have you restarted Solr?
2. Is the core you are trying to 'browse' a default core? If not, you need to include the core name in the URL. E.g. **/solr/collection1/browse**
3. Are your library statements in solrconfig.xml pointing at the right velocity jar? Use absolute path unless you are very sure that you know what your base directory is for the relative paths
4. Are you getting any errors in the server logs?

If all fails, start comparing what you have with the collection1 example in Solr distribution. it works there, so you can compare nearly line-by-line the relevant entries and even experiment with collection1 to make it more like your failing example.

Comment: I get 500 lazy error. I have tried giving /solr/collection1/browse.

   any idea ?

Comment: Probably did not define something. Maybe a handler in solrconfig.xml. Try doing the same with the example distribution and then looking for the differences between that and yours.

Comment: I have checked with the solrconfig.xml file of the collection1 of the distribution and mine. both are same . I haven't modified anything. Have not added anything. default distribution config I am running

Comment: And I am using solr4.6.0

Comment: Have you gone through all the steps in the answer? Specifically, step 3. If your directory is in different place, then the same solrconfig.xml will path due to the different relative library path. Also, look at the log file in details. Often there is a warning or error there.